# Count unique values in Raster Data in R

Tags: r, raster

I have these Raster Datasets, which look like this

```
      1  2  3  4  5
    1 NA NA NA 10 NA
    2 7  3  7  10 10
    3 NA 3  7  3  3
    4 9  9  NA 3  7
    5 3  NA 7  NA NA
```

via

```
    MyRaster1 <- raster("MyRaster_EUNIS1.tif")
    head(MyRaster1)
```

I created that table.
Using unique(MyRaster1) I get 3 7 9 10.

What I need are the counts of these unique values in the raster dataset.

I have tried quite a few ways around, one way works, but is a lot of trouble and I can't get a loop to work for all the raster datasets I have.

```
    Classes1 <- as.factor(unique(values(MyRaster1)))[!is.na(unique(values(MyRaster1)))]

    val1 <- unique(MyRaster1)
    Tab1 <- matrix(nrow = length(values(MyRaster1)), ncol = length(val))

    colnames(Tab1) <- levels(unique(Classes1))
    Tab1 <- Tab1[!is.na(Tab1[,1]),]

    colSums(Tab1)
```

It seems to work properly, until I try to delete the NA values. When I use colSums before that, I get NA as result for each column, after I delete the NA values, I get 0.

This is my first time using R, so I'm a real novice. I've researched quite a lot, but since I hardly understand the language at all, this is the furthest I have gotten.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
        table(MyRaster1) 
gives me this: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

The best result would be:

```
    3  7  9  10
    6  5  2  3
```

But I'd also be ok with a different format which I could use in Excel.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49557175/edit) your question to include your expected output based on the sample data?

Comment: And `table(MyRaster1)` does not work? If not, you could stack the columns and try again.

Comment: Also: this might work: `table(MyRaster1$layer@data@values)` but I am not sure how your data object looks like exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Use `raster::freq()`

Here's an example for the first two rows of your data:

```
r <- raster(matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,10,NA,7,3,7,10,10), nrow = 2, ncol =5))

> freq(r)
 value count
[1,]     3     1
[2,]     7     2
[3,]    10     3
[4,]    NA     4
```

Note that the freq function rounds unless explicitly told not to:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/freq